# How to divide dataset into balanced sets based on multiple variables

Tags: r, grouping, subset, balanced-groups

I have a large dataset I need to divide into multiple balanced sets.

The set looks something like the following:

```
> data<-matrix(runif(4000, min=0, max=10), nrow=500, ncol=8 )
> colnames(data)<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")
```

The sets, each containing for example 20 rows, will need to be balanced across multiple variables so that each subset ends up having a similar mean of B, C, D that's included in their subgroup compared to all the other subsets.

Is there a way to do that with R? Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Reproducible data
set.seed(2)
data<-matrix(runif(4000, min=0, max=10), nrow=500, ncol=8 )
colnames(data)<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")

data=as.data.frame(data)
```

**Updated Answer**

It's probably not possible to get similar means across sets within each column if you want to keep observations from a given row together. With 8 columns (as in your sample data), you'd need 25 20-row sets where each column A set has the same mean, each column B set has the same mean, etc. That's a lot of constraints. Probably there are, however, algorithms that could find the set membership assignment schedule that *minimizes* the difference in set means.

However, if you can separately take 20 observations from each column without regard to which row it came from, then here's one option:

```
# Group into sets with same means
same_means = data %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(set = c(rep(1:25, 10), rep(25:1, 10)))

# Check means by set for each column
same_means %>% 
  group_by(key, set) %>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(value)) %>% 
  spread(key, mean) %>% as.data.frame
```

> ```
>    set        A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H
> 1    1 4.940018 5.018584 5.117592 4.931069 5.016401 5.171896 4.886093 5.047926
> 2    2 4.946496 5.018578 5.124084 4.936461 5.017041 5.172817 4.887383 5.048850
> 3    3 4.947443 5.021511 5.125649 4.929010 5.015181 5.173983 4.880492 5.044192
> 4    4 4.948340 5.014958 5.126480 4.922940 5.007478 5.175898 4.878876 5.042789
> 5    5 4.943010 5.018506 5.123188 4.924283 5.019847 5.174981 4.869466 5.046532
> 6    6 4.942808 5.019945 5.123633 4.924036 5.019279 5.186053 4.870271 5.044757
> 7    7 4.945312 5.022991 5.120904 4.919835 5.019173 5.187910 4.869666 5.041317
> 8    8 4.947457 5.024992 5.125821 4.915033 5.016782 5.187996 4.867533 5.043262
> 9    9 4.936680 5.020040 5.128815 4.917770 5.022527 5.180950 4.864416 5.043587
> 10  10 4.943435 5.022840 5.122607 4.921102 5.018274 5.183719 4.872688 5.036263
> 11  11 4.942015 5.024077 5.121594 4.921965 5.015766 5.185075 4.880304 5.045362
> 12  12 4.944416 5.024906 5.119663 4.925396 5.023136 5.183449 4.887840 5.044733
> 13  13 4.946751 5.020960 5.127302 4.923513 5.014100 5.186527 4.889140 5.048425
> 14  14 4.949517 5.011549 5.127794 4.925720 5.006624 5.188227 4.882128 5.055608
> 15  15 4.943008 5.013135 5.130486 4.930377 5.002825 5.194421 4.884593 5.051968
> 16  16 4.939554 5.021875 5.129392 4.930384 5.005527 5.197746 4.883358 5.052474
> 17  17 4.935909 5.019139 5.131258 4.922536 5.003273 5.204442 4.884018 5.059162
> 18  18 4.935830 5.022633 5.129389 4.927106 5.008391 5.210277 4.877859 5.054829
> 19  19 4.936171 5.025452 5.127276 4.927904 5.007995 5.206972 4.873620 5.054192
> 20  20 4.942925 5.018719 5.127394 4.929643 5.005699 5.202787 4.869454 5.055665
> 21  21 4.941351 5.014454 5.125727 4.932884 5.008633 5.205170 4.870352 5.047728
> 22  22 4.933846 5.019311 5.130156 4.923804 5.012874 5.213346 4.874263 5.056290
> 23  23 4.928815 5.021575 5.139077 4.923665 5.017180 5.211699 4.876333 5.056836
> 24  24 4.928739 5.024419 5.140386 4.925559 5.012995 5.214019 4.880025 5.055182
> 25  25 4.929357 5.025198 5.134391 4.930061 5.008571 5.217005 4.885442 5.062630
> ```

**Original Answer**

```
# Randomly group data into 20-row groups
set.seed(104)
data = data %>% 
  mutate(set = sample(rep(1:(500/20), each=20)))

head(data)
```

> ```
>          A        B         C        D        E         F        G          H set
> 1 1.848823 6.920055 3.2283369 6.633721 6.794640 2.0288792 1.984295 2.09812642  10
> 2 7.023740 5.599569 0.4468325 5.198884 6.572196 0.9269249 9.700118 4.58840437  20
> 3 5.733263 3.426912 7.3168797 3.317611 8.301268 1.4466065 5.280740 0.09172101  19
> 4 1.680519 2.344975 4.9242313 6.163171 4.651894 2.2253335 1.175535 2.51299726  25
> 5 9.438393 4.296028 2.3563249 5.814513 1.717668 0.8130327 9.430833 0.68269106  19
> 6 9.434750 7.367007 1.2603451 5.952936 3.337172 5.2892300 5.139007 6.52763327   5
> ```

```
# Mean by set for each column
data %>% group_by(set) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean)
```

> ```
>      set        A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H
>  1     1 5.240236 6.143941 4.638874 5.367626 4.982008 4.200123 5.521844 5.083868
>  2     2 5.520983 5.257147 5.209941 4.504766 4.231175 3.642897 5.578811 6.439491
>  3     3 5.943011 3.556500 5.366094 4.583440 4.932206 4.725007 5.579103 5.420547
>  4     4 4.729387 4.755320 5.582982 4.763171 5.217154 5.224971 4.972047 3.892672
>  5     5 4.824812 4.527623 5.055745 4.556010 4.816255 4.426381 3.520427 6.398151
>  6     6 4.957994 7.517130 6.727288 4.757732 4.575019 6.220071 5.219651 5.130648
>  7     7 5.344701 4.650095 5.736826 5.161822 5.208502 5.645190 4.266679 4.243660
>  8     8 4.003065 4.578335 5.797876 4.968013 5.130712 6.192811 4.282839 5.669198
>  9     9 4.766465 4.395451 5.485031 4.577186 5.366829 5.653012 4.550389 4.367806
> 10    10 4.695404 5.295599 5.123817 5.358232 5.439788 5.643931 5.127332 5.089670
> # ... with 15 more rows
> ```

If the total number of rows in the data frame is not divisible by the number of rows you want in each set, then you can do the following when you create the sets:

```
data = data %>% 
  mutate(set = sample(rep(1:ceiling(500/20), each=20))[1:n()])
```

In this case, the set sizes will vary a bit with the number of data rows is not divisible by the desired number of rows in each set.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't this code randomly selecting 20 rows for each group? I want to select the 20 rows for each group so that the mean of the column "B" values, for example, remains the same across all the groups.

Comment: You want to select by row or can the 20 values be selected separately for each column?

Comment: No, each row has values that correspond to a single item, and I'm trying to make balanced groups of those items by using some of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach could be worth trying for someone in a similar position.

It is based on the numerical balancing in `groupdata2`'s `fold()` function, which allows creating groups with balanced means for a single column. By standardizing each of the columns and numerically balancing their rowwise sum, we might increase the chance of getting balanced means in the individual columns.

I compared this approach to creating groups randomly a few times and selecting the split with the least variance in means. It seems to be a bit better, but I'm not too convinced that this will hold in all contexts.

```r
# Attach dplyr and groupdata2
library(dplyr)
library(groupdata2)

set.seed(1)

# Create the dataset
data <- matrix(runif(4000, min = 0, max = 10), nrow = 500, ncol = 8)
colnames(data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
data <- dplyr::as_tibble(data)

# Standardize all columns and calculate row sums
data_std <- data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_all(.funs = function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))

# Create groups (new column called ".folds")
# We numerically balance the "total" column 
data_std <- data_std %>% 
  groupdata2::fold(k = 25, num_col = "total")  # k = 500/20=25

# Transfer the groups to the original (non-standardized) data frame
data$group <- data_std$.folds

# Check the means
data %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise_all(.funs = mean)

> # A tibble: 25 x 9
>    group     A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H
>    <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
>  1 1      4.48  5.05  4.80  5.65  5.04  4.60  5.12  4.85
>  2 2      5.57  5.17  3.21  5.46  4.46  5.89  5.06  4.79
>  3 3      4.33  6.02  4.57  6.18  4.76  3.79  5.94  3.71
>  4 4      4.51  4.62  4.62  5.27  4.65  5.41  5.26  5.23
>  5 5      4.55  5.10  4.19  5.41  5.28  5.39  5.57  4.23
>  6 6      4.82  4.74  6.10  4.34  4.82  5.08  4.89  4.81
>  7 7      5.88  4.49  4.13  3.91  5.62  4.75  5.46  5.26
>  8 8      4.11  5.50  5.61  4.23  5.30  4.60  4.96  5.35
>  9 9      4.30  3.74  6.45  5.60  3.56  4.92  5.57  5.32
> 10 10     5.26  5.50  4.35  5.29  4.53  4.75  4.49  5.45
> # … with 15 more rows

# Check the standard deviations of the means
# Could be used to compare methods
data %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise_all(.funs = mean) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sd))

> # A tibble: 1 x 8
>       A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 0.496 0.546 0.764 0.669 0.591 0.611 0.690 0.475
```

It might be best to compare the means and mean variances (or standard deviations as above) of different methods on the *standardized* data though. In that case, one could calculate the sum of the variances and minimize it.

```r
data_std %>% 
  dplyr::select(-total) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(.folds) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise_all(.funs = mean) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sd)) %>% 
  sum()

> 1.643989
```

### Comparing multiple balanced splits

The `fold()` function allows creating multiple *unique* grouping factors (splits) at once. So here, I will perform the numerically balanced split 20 times and find the grouping with the lowest sum of the standard deviations of the means. I'll further convert it to a function.

```r
create_multi_balanced_groups <- function(data, cols, k, num_tries){
  
  # Extract the variables of interest
  # We assume these are numeric but we could add a check
  data_to_balance <- data[, cols]
  
  # Standardize all columns
  # And calculate rowwise sums
  data_std <- data_to_balance %>% 
    dplyr::mutate_all(.funs = function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))
  
  # Create `num_tries` unique numerically balanced splits
  data_std <- data_std %>% 
    groupdata2::fold(
      k = k, 
      num_fold_cols = num_tries,
      num_col = "total"
    )
  
  # The new fold column names ".folds_1", ".folds_2", etc.
  fold_col_names <- paste0(".folds_", seq_len(num_tries))
  
  # Remove total column
  data_std <- data_std %>% 
    dplyr::select(-total)
  
  # Calculate score for each split
  # This could probably be done more efficiently without a for loop
  variance_scores <- c()
  for (fcol in fold_col_names){
    score <- data_std %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(!!as.name(fcol)) %>% 
      dplyr::summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean)) %>% 
      dplyr::summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sd)) %>% 
      sum()
    
    variance_scores <- append(variance_scores, score)
  }
  
  # Get the fold column with the lowest score
  lowest_fcol_index <- which.min(variance_scores)
  best_fcol <- fold_col_names[[lowest_fcol_index]]
  
  # Add the best fold column / grouping factor to the original data
  data[["group"]] <- data_std[[best_fcol]]
  
  # Return the original data and the score of the best fold column
  list(data, min(variance_scores))
  
}

# Run with 20 splits
set.seed(1)
data_grouped_and_score <- create_multi_balanced_groups(
  data = data,
  cols = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"),
  k = 25,
  num_tries = 20
)

# Check data
data_grouped_and_score[[1]]

> # A tibble: 500 x 9
>         A     B     C     D     E      F     G     H group
>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
>  1 5.86   6.54  0.500 2.88  5.70  9.67    2.29 3.01  2    
>  2 0.0895 4.69  5.71  0.343 8.95  7.73    5.76 9.58  1    
>  3 2.94   1.78  2.06  6.66  9.54  0.600   4.26 0.771 16   
>  4 2.77   1.52  0.723 8.11  8.95  1.37    6.32 6.24  7    
>  5 8.14   2.49  0.467 8.51  0.889 6.28    4.47 8.63  13   
>  6 2.60   8.23  9.17  5.14  2.85  8.54    8.94 0.619 23   
>  7 7.24   0.260 6.64  8.35  8.59  0.0862  1.73 8.10  5    
>  8 9.06   1.11  6.01  5.35  2.01  9.37    7.47 1.01  1    
>  9 9.49   5.48  3.64  1.94  3.24  2.49    3.63 5.52  7    
> 10 0.731  0.230 5.29  8.43  5.40  8.50    3.46 1.23  10   
> # … with 490 more rows

# Check score
data_grouped_and_score[[2]]

> 1.552656
```

By commenting out the `num_col = "total"` line, we can run this without the numerical balancing. For me, this gave a score of 1.615257.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `groupdata2` package. The `fold()` function can also balance a categorical column (`cat_col`) and keep all data points with the same ID in the same fold (`id_col`) (e.g. to avoid leakage in cross-validation). There's a very similar `partition()` function as well.